# Slide in/out with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've my divs as

```
<div id="summary" style=" width: 900px; margin: 0 auto;" >
    HTML content
</div>
<div id="details" style=" width: 900px; margin: 0 auto; display: none;" >
    Detail content
</divs>
```

My jquery code is like

```
$('#button').click( function() {
    $('#details').show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 1000);
    $('#summary').hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000);
});
```

While implementing this, the `div#summary` slides out on the left touching the edge of the monitor display & the `div#details` slides in from the right **but not from the edge of the monitor display.**

I want the `div#details` to slide in from the extreme right so that it looks like the div is sliding in from outside the screen.

How will I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to position it off the screen first, and try animating instead of using the slide function:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="summary" >
    HTML content
</div>
<div id="details">
    Detail content
</div>

<div id="button">click me</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}

div#button {
    cursor:pointer;
}

div#details {
    position:absolute;
    left:2000px;
    top:100px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#CCC;
}

div#summary {
    position:absolute;
    left:-500px;
    top:50px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#button').click( function() {
    $('#details, #summary').animate({left:'200px'});
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/7e92Y/